# How to display Start-Stop bands across horizontal time axis

Tags: python, powerbi

We want to display productive time on the phone, by employee, in a simple 1-dimensional time-axis chart.

Green in the chart represents time on the phone (between 'start' and 'stop':

[image]

Ideally we would like to do this natively in PowerBI, but if there's a simpler way in Python, we can embed it in our BI solution.

The data is simple:

| Agent | Start | Stop |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-09-16 11:45:48.900 | 2023-09-16 11:51:03.900 |
| 1 | 2023-09-16 11:56:06.720 | 2023-09-16 12:02:56.720 |
| ... | ... | ... |

I'm sure this is possible, we just haven't been able to get it done.

Thanks

Comment: One idea is to treat the start timestamp and the duration of the call as a vector, to be displayed horizontally on the axis.

Comment: Take a look at Deneb - this is fairly trivial.